# Bing: directionsManger.getAllWaypoints() doesn't return latitude/longitude

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, driving-directions

I am using Bing map ajax control. In my code i have something as below -

```js
function getMap()
      {
 map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('mnMap'), {
 credentials: 'MyKey', 
 mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road
          });
          map.setView({
 zoom: 4, 
 center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(defaultLat, defaultLan)
          });
          Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', {
callback: createDirectionsManager
          });

      }

      function createDirectionsManager()
      {
          if (!directionsManager) 
          {
              directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
          }
          directionsManager.resetDirections();
          directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('directionsPanel') });
          directionsErrorEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsError', displayRouteError );
          directionsUpdatedEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', displayUpdatedRoute );
      }

      function displayUpdatedRoute(status){

   // update waypoint text inputs based on dragged markers
          var legs = directionsManager.getAllWaypoints();
// Do some validation
      }

 function displayRouteError(error){

         // If the error is a viapoint error, display an error
         if (error.responseCode == Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteResponseCode.noSolution){
 directionsManager.resetDirections();
         }else if (error.responseCode == Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteResponseCode.dataSourceNotFound || error.responseCode == Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteResponseCode.tooFar){
directionsManager.resetDirections();
         }else{
directionsManager.resetDirections();
         }
      }
function getDirections(submit, send) {

directionsManager.resetDirections();
if (some test condition) {
          start = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(locInputs.first().attr("data-lat"), locInputs.first().attr("data-lng")) });
        } else {
          start = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: locInputs.first().val() });
        }
directionsManager.addWaypoint(start); // waypoint values come from UI based on user input string address
directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint);
directionsManager.addWaypoint(end);

directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('directionsPanel') });
        directionsManager.calculateDirections();
}
function saveTrip(){

 var legs = directionsManager.getAllWaypoints();

 // do some validations
 //ajax call to backend
}

$("#saveTripBtn").click(function() {
getDirections();
                saveTrip();

        }
```

getMap() is properly initialized, i can see the directions correctly being displayed. In the waypoints returned by directionsManager.getAllWaypoints(), none of the waypoint has location object inside it - as a result i am not getting lat/long. All i need is lat/long of each waypoint in savetrip() method, before calling the back-end code, which i do not see.

I am using a Developer key as of now. Let me know if i need to provide any more information.

Thanks in advance

Roshan

Comment: Just wanted to add- if i pass the address query SearchManager class - i do get lat/long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the getLocation method on the Waypoint object to get it's location coordinates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312838.aspx

Here is a working code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        var map, directionsManager;

        function GetMap() { 
           map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), { 
               credentials: 'YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY'
           }); 

           Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', {
            callback: getDirections
           });
       }

       function getDirections() {
            if (!directionsManager) 
            {
               directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
            }

            directionsManager.resetDirections();

            var start = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: "Seattle, WA" });
            var end = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: "Portland, OR" });

            directionsManager.addWaypoint(start); 
            directionsManager.addWaypoint(end);
            directionsManager.calculateDirections(); 
        }

        function getWaypoints(){
            var wp = directionsManager.getAllWaypoints();

            var text = '';

            for(var i=0;i<wp.length;i++){
                var loc = wp[i].getLocation();
                text += 'waypoint ' + i + ': ' + loc.latitude + ', ' + loc.longitude + '\r\n';
            }

            document.getElementById('output').innerText = text;
        }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
    <div id='myMap' style=";width:600px;height:400px;"></div><br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="getWaypoints()" value="Get Waypoints" /><br/>
    <div id="output"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect you are using it incorrectly. Take a look at the code sample. This works.

Comment: Thanks Ricky. 

The mistake was - I was calling 

directionsManager.getAllWaypoints()
before the following event completed. As a result never received location data. 
directionsUpdatedEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', displayUpdatedRoute );
      }